# How to pass a Map to controller throw Executions.createComponents(...) ? (ZK)

Tags: java, zk

I make a pop-up Window.

```
Window window = (Window)Executions.createComponents("./org.zul", null, **map**);
```

**./org.zul** have a **EditController.java** How this controller can get **map** ?
thanks

Comment: Can you Share Little bit more code, how you call the above code?

Comment: Executions.getCurrent().getArg() is get empty map, but I'm shure, that not empty map has been sent.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this to open popup/modal window

```
Map args = new HashMap();
args.put("myMap", thisIsMyMap);
popupWin = (Window)Executions.createComponents("org.zul", null, args);
// popupWin.setClosable(true);
popupWin.doModal();
```

and this in **EditController.java**

```
thisIsMyMap = (HashMap) Executions.getCurrent().getArg().get("myMap");
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be something like this

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
defaultReorderSelected = new ListModelList<ReorderData>()
args.put("availableList", availableReorderList);
args.put("defaultSelected", defaultReorderSelected);
public void createReorderModal(Component comp, Map args) {
Executions.getCurrent().createComponents("/core/component/model_window_new.zul",
                comp, args);

}
```

And in `afterCompose()` method of **model_window_new.zul** viewModel you have to write same name which you used in Key of `Map`

```
    @AfterCompose
    public void doAfterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view,
    @ExecutionArgParam("availableList") ListModelList<SortData> availableList,
                @ExecutionArgParam("defaultSelected") ListModelList<SortData> defaultSelectedList){
//Your Business Logic.
}
```